# EF CTP5 which code generation item to choose?

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3, poco, entity-framework-ctp5, ef-code-first

With EF 4.1 on the way and CTP5 being available for few months now I've decided to try out the new functionality. As I see, there are multiple generation items available (`DbContext` and three different `ObjectContext's`). I also noticed they are not interchangable - I was first using the POCO ObjectContext in one of my app and today switched to DbContext and my entire repository broke. It was based on `LoadProperty()` methods, `DeleteObject()` and `AddObject()` methods and those are all missing on `DbSet` class which is used in `DbContext` generation.

I know there's a great blog series here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-1-introduction-and-model.aspx introducing the new functionality but it never really says when to choose what.

My requirements are:

- ASP.NET MVC application, so lazy
  loading mostly won't work coz at page
  render it will say that context has
  already been disposed (that's why I
  need easy support for explicit
  loading - in EF4 I did it via
  `Include()`, using POCO context I did
  it through `LoadProperty()` and now
  in `DbContext` I believe I will use
  the strongly typed `Include()`).
- We probably won't be needing code-first
  features (but you never know).

Comment: ideally the answer will provide the pros/cons for each of the options available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference between those two is mostly in [API and feature set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086548/ef-poco-code-only-vs-ef-poco-with-entity-data-model/5089398#5089398). `DbContext` of course have `Include` for query and `Load` but you will find it elsewhere. Moreover when using CTP5 assembly you will have strongy typed `Include` for both `ObjectSet` and `DbSet` ([available on IQueryable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766122/how-can-i-convert-a-dbqueryt-to-an-objectqueryt) as extension method).

Explicit loading (equivalent to `LoadProperty`) is performed by `Load` method on `DbReferenceEntry<T>` or `DbCollectionEntry<T>` - check [Explicit loading related entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx). It works even better then `LoadProperty` because you can define filter for loading.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting with the wrong assumption that you can't use lazy load with MVC.

If you manage the context at a higher level, you'll be able to do that without problems.

Comment: Check out the many examples that exist for session-per-request using NHibernate. A NH `ISession` roughly corresponds to an EF `DbContext`

Comment: I'm not using NHibernate but I do have IoC with Ninject in place and context per request, I guess that's it. However lazy loading in this configuration does not work with POCO context but it does with DbContext (just tried it out today).