# Difference in DAL with repository pattern and DAL without repository pattern?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, repository-pattern

Some time back I started using EF as a DAL and from tutorials and videos come to know about repository pattern and Unit of work patterns.

About repository I learned it is an abstraction over DAL and it separate business logic from data access code. Also that it avoid reputation of data access code and help in unit testing.

I understand repository pattern is a particular way of making DAL. But what it brings ? I am not getting. My confusion is just making a DAL (a separate class library/ project) it will also give these benefits (separate data access logic from business logic, save data access code reputation, help in unit testing etc).

Probably I am still missing benefits of repository patren. Please guide me on this.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401957/repository-pattern-with-entity-framework/5402554#5402554

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repository Pattern vs DAL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291344/repository-pattern-vs-dal)

Answer (score 1):

Data Access Layer is supposed to deal with data sources like databases, but to achieve some higher level goals as described by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) you need repository pattern.

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)

> - You want to maximize the amount of code that can be tested with
>     automation and to isolate the data layer to support unit testing.
> - You access the data source from many locations and want to apply
>     centrally managed, consistent access rules and logic.
> - You want to implement and centralize a caching strategy for the data source. You
>     want to improve the code's maintainability and readability by
>     separating business logic from data or service access logic.
> - You want to use business entities that are strongly typed so that you can
>     identify problems at compile time instead of at run time.
> - You want to
>     associate a behavior with the related data. For example, you want to
>     calculate fields or enforce complex relationships or business rules
>     between the data elements within an entity.
> - You want to apply a
>     domain model to simplify complex business logic.

Comment: Asif in case of DAL (without repository), again I will have a just DAL classes where only I will be doing changes. I couldn't really get its benefit.