# Deferred execution the in repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ienumerable, repository-pattern, iqueryable

In my `UserRepository` I have a `GetActive` method:

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetActive()
{
    var users = context.Set<UserTbl>().Where(x => x.IsActive);

    foreach(var user in users)
    {
        yield return entityMapper.CreateFrom(user);
    }
}
```

The `entityMapper` is used to map from an EF-generated `UserTbl` to the `User` domain entity.

There exists thousands of users so I want the `GetActive` method to defer execution while returning the `IEnumerable<User>` so that the entire list isn't pulled unnecessarily.  I have done that above with the `foreach` and `yield`.

When testing, it seems that the all the data is being fetched regardless.  The following two calls take the same time:

```
// Get only 5 users in memory
var someUsers = UserRepository.GetActive().Take(5).ToList();

// Get all 100,000 users into memory
var allUsers = UserRepository.GetActive().ToList();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The easiest way is to include pagination as the repository method arguments  'GetActive(int skip, int take)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you use `foreach`, the data is enumerated. You have to use `IQueryable` only until the `ToList` method. Your idea about deferring data using `IEnumerable` seem nice, but it is wrong. `IEnumerable` always returns all data, it just doesn't force the provider of the data to hold it all in memory. You have to use `IQueryable` if you want to provider to return pieces of data. But then, you can't use `foreach` and `yield`, because it always enumerates all data in it's parameter.
Only way to do what you want is to pass the required query into the `GetActive` method.

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetActive(Func<IQueryable<User>, IQueryable<User>> modifier)
{
    var users = modifier(context.Set<UserTbl>().Where(x => x.IsActive));

    foreach(var user in users)
    {
        yield return entityMapper.CreateFrom(user);
    }
}

// Get only 5 users in memory
var someUsers = UserRepository.GetActive(q=>q.Take(5)).ToList();

// Get all 100,000 users into memory
var allUsers = UserRepository.GetActive(q=>q).ToList();
```

But I would really recommend not having repositories in your architecture at all. They introduce needless complexity over already complex ORM. See more in [Repository pattern with Entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401957/repository-pattern-with-entity-framework)

Comment: I would recommend to **use** repositories IF you want the app to be decoupled from persistence. ORM or not, it doesn't matter. If you're using an ORM don't make the mistake to define a domain object on top of an ORM entity. The repository can happily use an ORM without exposing it, acting as a high level mapper and most importantly as anti corruption layer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer to my question, Euphoric.  Although, if anything, using repositories has abstracted away many of the data complexities that we deal with and has ensured a high degree of testibility across our codebase.