# What are the advantages/disadvantages of using DB First versus Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I know `enum`s are currently only available in the June 2011 CTP and won't be in 4.2. What other factors would make someone choose one or the other?

Answer (score 2):

Ladislav Mrnka has a [great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446316/ef-4-1-code-first-vs-model-database-first/5446587#5446587) that breaks down the differences between DB First, Code First and Model First. I strongly suggest that you go read it and upvote it.

Besides that, I would only add the following points:

- <s>Even in the June 2011 CTP, Enum support is limited, so you might
  want to see if any of those issues are showstoppers for you.</s> *Update*: EF5+ supports [Enums with EF Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj248772) and [Code First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576).
- If you are implementing EF against an Oracle DB, **and you
        don't want to pay for a data provider**, then you will be
        without Code First, as Oracle's [own provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html) <s>(still in beta)</s>
        doesn't support it.

Edit: here is another comprehensive [answer from Ladislav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797312/ef-model-first-or-code-first-approach).

Answer (score 1):

See **Entity Framework Development Approaches** in
http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score -2):

**Advantages** : One common syntax ( LINQ / Yoda ) for all object queries whether it is database or not , Pretty fast if used as intended , easy to implement SoC , less coding required to accomplish complex tasks

**Disadvantages** : you have to think in a non traditional way of handling data , not available for every database

**Disadvantage**: If there is any schema change in database FE won’t work!!! You have to update the schema in solution as well!!!

**Advantage**: Its fast and straight forward using LINQ/FE objects For Add/Modify/Delete/Update.

**Advantages**:-Easy to map business objects (with drag & drop tables on environment).
-It keeps a good performance when you work with a small / middle domain model.

**Disadvantages**:-It's limited when you work with a huge domain model.
-Scalability.