# What is the best approach to implement Entity Framework for a messy database?

Tags: .net, architecture, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have in front of me a scenario in which an application needs to be overhauled architecturally and i want to use EF 4.3 to be the ORM part of the architecture.

The database used by the application is messy and some of the tables lack relations/keys.

I want to evaluate before i go about designing the architecture as to what would be the best foot forward - code first POCO or the EDMX approach?

Comment: Without knowing your database, it is going to be very hard to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently created an EDMX on a database schema lacking some foreign keys as well. It is not hard to create associations by hand. For that task, the visual designer surface comes in handy. So I would use edmx.

With code-first I think it is quite a hassle to manufacture classes matching the database design.

For a thorough general discussion, see [EF Model First or Code First Approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797312/ef-model-first-or-code-first-approach).