# ASP.NET MVC Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

When building an MVC application from scratch without a pre-existing database, is using the code-first approach the best way to do it?
While most applications are database-centric, it is perhaps the schema rather than the database itself that governs how the app is built around it. As such, I think a code-first approach isn't too bad. It was late to the party (happened after database-first and model-first), but I think the code-first approach will become the norm soon.
What's your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i think that this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797312/ef-model-first-or-code-first-approach) can provide you with more information

In my opinion both of the approaches are useful. A developer/company needs to decide what is the best approach for there system, in some situation.

I think one good distinguish is Big and complex against small and simple applications

I think that developers or companies will prefer "DataBase First" approach when they builds complex application. In most cases DBA's will be needed in such project.
In those cases the project will include Store Procedures/ Triggers and maybe also a Data-ware house

In the other hand when you build a small application with one of small group of developers you probably prefer using "Code First" approach

again this is my opinion...